# Web user and Admin restriction to certain controllers and views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership, cloud

I am developing a cloud application on ASP.Net MVC. I have problems in implementation of login system.

**What I did**
I used `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(...)` for login of web users. 
and `Authorize` in controller like that

```
  [Authorize]
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult AdminPage(){...}
```

**What the Problem is**
When i `sign in` with web users `credentials` and tries to access admin controllers it have nothing to stop that user and he can access all(including admin pages).

What type of **Login implimentation** should i use to tackle this. Remember keep the `security` in mind.

I also saw `ASP.Net MemberShip Class` but it generates Database on its own. Can it be mold and works good with user define Database.

Comment: what do you mean by admin pages?what you have done to separate them as admin pages?

did you try rolling?

 `[Authorize(Roles="admin")]`

Comment: where to define roles of users when i have different user tables for web users and website admin

Answer (score 2):

You can specify roles on the `Authorize` attribute.

**Example**

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
```

This means that only users that have a role of admin will have access to that method.

### Update

If you are using custom roles, you will need to create a `Custom Role Provider`.  This will allow you to override the `RoleProvider` methods and add your own logic.

**Example**

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        // Custom logic
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        // Custom logic
    }

    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    {
        // Custom logic
    }
}
```

A detailed tutorial can be found here [Custom Role Providers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607392/Custom-Role-Providers)

Comment: i saw that but where to define roles of users

Comment: i have different user tables for web users and website admin

Comment: From the sounds of it you will need to create a `Custom Role Provider`.  This link has a detailed example of doing this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607392/Custom-Role-Providers

Answer (score 1):

*I do not want to steal Colin Bacon's answer. Instead, I'll add some additional information; I hope second opinion won't hurt.*

You need `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` to restrict access to Admin role only like this -

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult AdminPage(){...}
```

Since your MVC application already uses FormsAuthentication, you **do not need to use MembershipProvider**.

However, you need to implement Custom Role Provider and override [GetRolesForUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.getrolesforuser.aspx) method **(the rest of the methods are optional)**.

Basically, AuthorizeAttribute will call GetRolesForUser method when a user access an action with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`.

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        // Query admin table.
        if(user is in admin table)
            return new[] {"Admin"}; 

        return new[] {};            
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first in web.config add this (system.web)

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider,WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider,WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

then add this line to Global.asax in Application_Start

```
WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection",
                   "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

then you can add users to roles like this

```
var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;

roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "username1", "username2", ... },
                      new[] { "role1", "role2", .... });
```

then on the controllers or methods you can add AuthorizeAttribute like below

```
[Authorize(Roles="role1,role2,...")]
```

Comment: And how to Add my SQLServer DB to it?

Comment: How to add my DB SQLServer DB in that this creates a New Db (.mdf file)

Comment: use your connection string in the web.config, "DefaultConnection" change it to your connection string name